# Cartesian multiplication of two sets where the member of each set is a set

Tags: set, union, multiplication, cplex

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NFO6wgxAH868DVJzZYGZ4-2ja6Ci-I39?usp=sharing)I have two expressions that I want to get a member-by-member union of. But the problem is where the member of each expression is a set.

I have a graph from which I obtained two expressions where the first two terms include all odd subsets of odd nodes (it has 128 members) and the second term includes all even subsets of even nodes (it has 7 members).
I want to define a new expression called Sub_odd_even which contains the union of all the previous two expressions. for example:
`A=[{1,2,3},{4}] B=[{6}] AB = [{1,2,3,6},{4,6}]`

I tried the following codes, but none of them were correct. cplex software itself errors them

`   int num_odd_even1 = card(Sub_even_even);
int num_odd_even2 = card(Sub_odd_odd);
int num_odd_even = odd_even1 * odd_even2

```
{int} Sub_odd_even = {i * j | i in Sub_odd_odd, j in Sub_even_even};
{int} Sub_odd_even = {foreach (i in Sub_odd_odd, j in Sub_even_even) i * j};
{int} Sub_odd_evev[oe in num_odd_even] = {item(Sub_odd, i-1) | i in 1..subr and j in 1..subre};
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shared an example in https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/cartesianproduct2.mod

```
// Cartesian product for a given number of sets

tuple Tset {
        {string} members;
}

{Tset} setOfTuples = {<{"1","2"}>,<{"4","5","6"}>,<{"8","9"}>};

// Here we have 3 dimensions

{Tset} result=union (k in item(setOfTuples,2).members,
     j in  item(setOfTuples,1).members,
     i in item(setOfTuples,0).members)
{<{i,j,k}>};

execute
{
  writeln(result);
}

/*

which gives

{<{"1" "4" "8"}> <{"2" "4" "8"}> <{"1" "5" "8"}> <{"2" "5" "8"}>
     <{"1" "6" "8"}> <{"2" "6" "8"}> <{"1" "4" "9"}>
     <{"2" "4" "9"}> <{"1" "5" "9"}> <{"2" "5" "9"}>
     <{"1" "6" "9"}> <{"2" "6" "9"}>}
     
     */
```

and then for your second question about how to do the union:

```
tuple t
{
  {int} s1;
  {int} s2;
}

{t} s={<{1},{5,6}>};

{int} res[i in s]=i.s1 union i.s2;

execute
{
  writeln(res);
}
```

which gives

```
[{1 5 6}]
```

Comment: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eCNded_QT5Bb9UTkU7AIXx8naSiLbwRE/view?usp=sharing)I made the following changes and you can see the result in the picture But I want it to have only one column, for example, the first row should be {1, 5, 6}

`tuple Tset { {int} s1; {int} s2; } {Tset} result = {<Sub_odd_odd[s1], Sub_even_even[s2]> |s1 in subr, s2 in subre};`

Comment: Do not hesitate to accept the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eCNded_QT5Bb9UTkU7AIXx8naSiLbwRE/view?usp=sharing)I made the following changes and you can see the result in the picture
But I want it to have only one column, for example, the first row should be {1, 5, 6}

> tuple Tset {
> {int} s1;
> {int} s2; }
> {Tset} result = {<Sub_odd_odd[s1], Sub_even_even[s2]> |s1 in subr, s2
> in subre};

Comment: Please do not add links to google drive that are versatile but copy paste the image directly in the SO answer

Comment: I tried a lot to do this, but it didn't work. At first, I copied and pasted in the photo section, but it gave an error and said to put a link, and when I went to the link section, it gave me a server problem.